# Rasterize shp polygons with gdal_rasterize and ALL_TOUCHED - adjacent polygons - select value for burn in

Tags: python, gdal, shapefile, gdal-rasterize

I have a shapefile with streets as polygons, each polygon as an attribute describing its type (for emission modeling). Now I have a highway with an adjacent minor road. When I raster this shapefile layer with 32m resolution without ALL_TOUCHED (-at), the streets do not appear as cohesive pixel rows in the raster. With ALL_TOUCHED, they do. However, as the minor road and the highway are close by, the type that is burned into the raster corresponds largely to the minor road, I would want the highway to be dominant (lower type numbers are in my case more important). Can I tell gdal_rasterize, it should favor smaller attribute values for burning? Workaround would be to rasterize certain street types separately and then numpy.minimum.reduce() it to the lowest value, but it's not as beautiful.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: No, sorry. I went with the workaround as described.